# Setting java classpath for lucene on a mac

Tags: java, macos, lucene, classpath

I downloaded the lucene jars and then added them to the CLASSPATH variable via my .bash_profile, the paths to the jars display correctly in the terminal.

```
export CLASSPATH=/Users/dk/lucene-3.4.0/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/dk/lucene-3.4.0/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar

echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/dk/lucene-3.4.0/lucene-core-3.4.0.jar:/Users/dk/lucene-3.4.0/contrib/demo/lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
```

However, java still complains to me when I try to run the demo:

```
java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs .

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
......
```

I was able to follow this exact procedure to get the lucene demo working on an ubuntu machine, now I just want it to be able to run on my mac. It seems there are similar questions floating around stackoverflow but none of them seem to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have your paths right? It works fine for me.

```
.../lucene-3.4.0/tmp $ ls
lucene-core-3.4.0.jar   lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
.../lucene-3.4.0/tmp $ export CLASSPATH=./lucene-core-3.4.0.jar:./lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
.../lucene-3.4.0/tmp $ echo $CLASSPATH
./lucene-core-3.4.0.jar:./lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
.../lucene-3.4.0/tmp $ java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs .
Indexing to directory 'index'...
adding ./lucene-core-3.4.0.jar
adding ./lucene-demo-3.4.0.jar
1485 total milliseconds
.../lucene-3.4.0/tmp $
```

Comment: you are correct, I mistakenly left out a part of the path! silly question, but is it possible to get tab completion for the jars in the classpath as well? So far I have to type out the full name of the class, which is annoying.

Comment: @Damonkashu Yeah, classpaths can be a pain. Btw, I generally recommend against an environment classpath--better to set it up in a shell script. I know you *could* implement classname completion in bash (search for "bash-completion") but I don't know how. Zsh has it by default, which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

As of Lucene 6.0, these seem to work:

```
java -cp ./core/lucene-core-6.0.0.jar:./analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-6.0.0.jar:./demo/lucene-demo-6.0.0.jar  org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs <directory to index>
```

For the search demo:

```
java -cp ./core/lucene-core-6.0.0.jar:./analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-6.0.0.jar:./queryparser/lucene-queryparser-6.0.0.jar:./demo/lucene-demo-6.0.0.jar  org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles
```